# Cannot Understand nth Derivative of x/ArcTan[x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, trigonometry

The nth derivative of `x/ArcTan[x]`:

```
f[x_, n_] = D[x/ArcTan[x], {x, n}]
```

Evaluates to:

[image]

I cannot get this general from to return as a callable function:

[image]

What is the appropriate series form of the function returned here?

Please note that I would like the series representation, not a function which delay calls the nth derivative.

Thank you!

Comment: If you do `f[x,2] // FullForm` you will see that it is of the form `Inactive[...]`. Therefore perhaps `f[x,2] // Activate` is what you want? (I may have misunderstood the question.)

Comment: `Series[x/ArcTan[x], {x, 0, 10}]` ?

Comment: What about `Series[f[x,2]//Activate,{x,0,5}]`?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what results you want. For example, what do you want `f[x,2]` to evaluate to?

Comment: You could do `f[n_]:=Function[x,Evaluate[D[x/ArcTan[x],{x,n}]]]` - make sure you use `:=` (`SetDelayed`). Then `f[1][x]` gives you what you want, and `f[1][2.0]` evaluates correctly.

Comment: If you're looking for a symbolic expression for an arbitrary derivative, it does not look to me that you can avoid using the partial Bell polynomial: `With[{n = 11}, D[x/ArcTan[x], {x, n}] == n Sum[(-1)^k k! ArcTan[x]^(-k - 1) BellY[n - 1, k, Table[2^(-1 + i) Sqrt[Pi] x^(1 - i) HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, 1}, {1 - i/2, (3 - i)/2}, -x^2], {i, n - k}]], {k, n - 1}] + x Sum[(-1)^k k! ArcTan[x]^(-k - 1) BellY[n, k, Table[2^(-1 + i) Sqrt[Pi] x^(1 - i) HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, 1}, {1 - i/2, (3 - i)/2}, -x^2], {i, n - k + 1}]], {k, n}] // Simplify]`